# Plot distances between points matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, pdist

I've made a plot of 10 points

`10                       10
248,628959661970    66,9462583977501
451,638770451973    939,398361884535
227,712826026548    18,1775336366957
804,449583613070    683,838613746355
986,104241895970    783,736480083219
29,9919502693899    534,137567882728
535,664190667238    885,359450931142
87,0772199008924    899,004898906140
990                        990`

With the first column as x-coordinates and the other column as y-coordinates

Leading to the following Plot:
Using the following code: `scatter(Problem.Points(:,1),Problem.Points(:,2),'.b')`
[image: Plot]

I then also calculated the euclidean distances using `Problem.DistanceMatrix = pdist(Problem.Points);
Problem.DistanceMatrix = squareform(Problem.DistanceMatrix);`

I replaced the distances by 1*10^6 when they are larger than a certain value.
This lead to the following table:

[image: Euclidean distances]

Then, I would like to plot the lines between the corresponding points, preferably with their distances, but only in case the distance < 1*10^6.

Specifically i want to plot the line [1,2] [1,4] [1,7] [2,4] etc.

My question is, can this be done and how?

Comment: (1) Can you be more specific about what you mean when you say you would like to "plot the lines," e.g. produce a line plot where each column of the table is a line, or produce a heatmap? In general, if `D` is a matrix then you can exclude values of `D` over `max_value` from a plot by replacing them by `NaN`s as follows: `D(D > max_value) = NaN;`. (2) Could you also include your code so we can replicate it exactly?

Comment: I just want to clarify. You would like to draw lines, on the same scatter plot between all of the points that are below you 1e6 criteria?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming one set of your data is in something called `xdata` and the other in `ydata` and then the distances in `distances`, the following code should accomplish what you want.

```
hold on
for k = 1:length(xdata)
    for j = 1:length(ydata)
        if(distances(k,j) < 1e6)
            plot([xdata(k) xdata(j)], [ydata(k) ydata(j)]);
        end
    end
end
```

You just need to iterate through your matrix and then if the value is less than 1e6, then plot the line between the kth and jth index points.  This will however double plot lines, so it will plot from k to j, and also from j to k, but it is quick to code and easy to understand.  I got the following plot with this.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
P = [
    10.0000000000000  10.0000000000000;
   248.6289596619700  66.9462583977501;
   451.6387704519730 939.3983618845350;
   227.7128260265480  18.1775336366957;
   804.4495836130700 683.8386137463550;
   986.1042418959700 783.7364800832190;
    29.9919502693899 534.1375678827280;
   535.6641906672380 885.3594509311420;
    87.0772199008924 899.0048989061400;
   990.0000000000000 990.0000000000000
];
P_len = size(P,1);

D = squareform(pdist(P));
D(D > 600) = 1e6;

scatter(P(:,1),P(:,2),'*b');

hold on;

for i = 1:P_len
    pi = P(i,:);

    for j = 1:P_len
        pj = P(j,:);
        d = D(i,j);

        if ((d > 0) && (d < 1e6))
            plot([pi(1) pj(1)],[pi(2) pj(2)],'-r');
        end
    end
end

hold off;
```

Final output:

[image: Output]

On a side note, the part in which you replaces the distance values trespassing a certain treshold (it looks like it's `600` by looking at your distances matrix) with `1e6` can be avoided by just inserting that threshold into the loop for plotting the lines. I mean... it's not wrong, but I just think it's an unnecessary step.

```
D = squareform(pdist(P));

% ...

if ((d > 0) && (d < 600))
    plot([pi(1) pj(1)],[pi(2) pj(2)],'-r');
end
```

Answer (score 0):

A friend of mine suggested using gplot

```
gplot(Problem.AdjM, Problem.Points(:,:), '-o')
```

With problem.points as the coordinates and Problem.AdjM as the adjacency matrix. The Adjacency matrix was generated like this:

```
Problem.AdjM=Problem.DistanceMatrix;
Problem.AdjM(Problem.AdjM==1000000)=0;
Problem.AdjM(Problem.AdjM>0)=1;
```

Since the distances of 1*10^6 was the replacement of a distance that is too large, I put the adjacency there to 0 and all the other to 1.

This lead to the following plot, which was more or less what I wanted:

[image: Points Linked Together]

Since you people have been helping me in such a wonderful way, I just wanted to add this:

I added J. Mel's solution to my code, leading to two exactly the same figures: 
[image: My solution]
[image: J Mel's solution]

Since the figures get the same outcome, both methods should be all right. Furthermore, since Tommasso's and J Mel's outcomes were equal earlier, Tommasso's code must also be correct.

Many thanks to both of you and all other people contributing!

Comment: Isn't that graph missing some points? Points 2 and 4 for example are missing while they should be there since [1,4] and [1,2] fit your distance criteria.

Comment: That's because i reran the script, and the points are generated randomly. Sorry for not clarifying